# localtime() giving incorrect value

Tags: c, mplab

There is loads of code online that has led me to believe that the following will give me the current time. However, this isn't the case. I'm getting what I believe to be the UNIX epoch time; 1st of Jan 1970 00:00;00.

It's becoming really annoying now, why aren't I getting the current time as governed by my computers system clock? I'm doing this for an embedded system, in C. The IDE is mplab.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main () {

time_t time_raw_format;
struct tm * ptr_time;

time ( &time_raw_format );
ptr_time = localtime ( &time_raw_format );
printf ("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(ptr_time));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are you getting and what are you expecting? Your code works fine for me.

Comment: You may want to check what `time` returns, to make sure it succeeds. And of course check your clock.

Comment: I expect the current time; 16:51, 20th of May, 2013. I'm getting, as I say, 00:00 1st of Jan, 1970.

Comment: [tag:status-no-repro] Works here. Check what Joachim Pileborg said to check.

Comment: Are you guys all getting the current date in your respective countries? time is also returning circa midnight 1970. My system clock is correct.

Comment: If that is what `time()` is returning, then `localtime()` will follow.

Comment: this is using the standard time.h library within the XC16 compiler. I'll try another library.

Comment: What about the return value of `time()`, not just what is passed back in the output parameter. Does it equal `(time_t)-1`? If so, you need to check `errno`.

Comment: What hardware are you using and does it have an auto-setting realtime clock.  On just a basic PIC I guess I wouldn't expect to get anything meaningful from the call.  Even running it in the IDE on your machine it probably returns that as the default.

Comment: It's a dsPIC33F, but surely I'm not doing anything with hardware as of yet? I'm just trying to use MPLAB to recall the date/time from my system. I've also tried debugging with the simulator.

Comment: The MPLAB libraries have no interaction with your local machine as the intent is to run on end hardware so none of the standard C calls interact with the local hardware.  Not sure if it's even possible to link in libraries that would do that.  Be interested to know if you figure that out.

Comment: Wow, how irritating. I just gave up in MPLAB and downloaded and ran the code in Visual Studio; gives the correct time and date. If you have any ideas on how to get the current system time into MPLAB I'd be very happy to hear it.

Comment: Not sure if there is a way.  Could I ask why you need the current time?  Since you'll be running this on PIC hardware I'm assuming this is just to test some functionality that's you'll need so an option might be to create a dummy function to call in DEBUG mode that will return you a more useful date.  Just a thought.

Comment: I've got my PIC using SPI to communicate with an SD card which works well, but the file creation and editing times are incorrect. I've since been playing around with the RTCC module which I've got ticking over every second (1HZ), but to set the current year/month/day, etc I'd have to enter manually, which will be irritating every time I want to reprogram the PIC. I was hoping for some code which will grab the current time during compiling and automatically set the date/time for when my PIC is creating/editing files on the SD card. Ideas?

Comment: That's a tricky one indeed.  I won't put this as an answer because I don't have the steps at the moment but if you're using MPLABX and the make system you could possibly generate one or multiple #defines that would configure the RTC to have the current date/time.  The big problem is that you then lock it in time so if the device ever loses power and the RTCC can't keep counting, the time will reset to the compile time.  Without some interaction with the device (wireless update, mechanic UI, etc) it will be hard to maintain an accurate time.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard does not require the time to be available, and the `time` routine may return –1 (and place it in the pointed-to location). Your code does not check the return value, so there is no reason to believe any of the code after that performs any useful operations. Therefore, the first thing to do is check the return value of `time`.

Similarly, `localtime` may return a null pointer if conversion to local time is not possible, and your code does not check the return value of `localtime`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but with the help of some other members we've localised it to an MPLAB issue. Apparently embedded C libraries have trouble communicating with the computer/system. The code works fine in Visual Studio.